# Does past perfect mean that in this case the action was totally finished?

Tags: past-perfect

And I didn’t want to be told what to do. I wanted to be a writer, even though I didn’t know what it meant. I’**d always read** a lot, and a few writers had a huge effect on me

I understand why past perfect is used. He began to read  before he wanted to be a writer and before he knew what being a writer mean . But does that mean he had also stop reading by the time writers had effect on him.I don't think so but often using past perfect indicates that the action is finished.

https://www.newyorker.com/culture/the-new-yorker-interview/how-richard-hell-found-his-vocation

Comment: The writer is referring to a time in the past when he didn’t want to be told what to do, because he knew he wanted to be a writer. He's *explaining / expanding* on how he felt back then by pointing out that ***even before that time*** he had always read a lot. It's not really meaningful to ask whether he'd "finished" reading a lot by the time he started resenting people telling him what to do.

Comment: If the writer had started with Present Tense *And I **don't** want to be told what to do. I **want** to be a writer...* then he'd have used Present Perfect ***I’ve / I have** always read a lot* (we wouldn't normally use Simple Present ***I read a lot*** in such contexts, and we'd *never* include the word ***always*** in that statement anyway).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the verb is not *telic*, not moving towards an ending or a finish of some kind, then using it in a past perfect construction which situates the action prior to some other action in the past does not imply that those prior actions had completed or come to an end, and merely indicates when they took place relative to the reference time:

Atelic:

> I had always **enjoyed** swimming, so it was only natural that when I got out of school I wanted to find a job where I could live near water.

There is no reason to think the speaker has lost their love of swimming.

Telic:

> I had **drunk** the iced tea in my glass, so when the host asked me if I would like some more ice, I said no thank you.

The glass has no tea in it. The tea has been drunk.